# Not all Posts.Title get displayed

Tags: support, data-explorer

When I run the following not all the records diplay a value in the Title field:

```
SELECT
    Users.DisplayName,
    Posts.OwnerDisplayName,
    Posts.Title,
    Posts.Score
FROM 
    Posts 
    INNER JOIN Users ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Users.id    
WHERE 
    Users.DisplayName = 'whytheq'
ORDER BY 4 desc
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of your posts are answers, which don't have the title field populated.

You can left join back to `Posts` on `ParentId` and then coalesce the title field if you want the title displayed in all cases, or select `Posts.Id AS [Post Link]`, which will give you the title as a link to the post in question.

Also note that usernames are not unique, so generally you'd want to select using your user ID as input, which Data Explorer will attempt to guess for you automatically based on your email hash if you're a registered user and you do something like `WHERE Posts.OwnerUserId == ##UserId##`.

Comment: Or add `and Posts.PostTypeId = 1` to the WHERE clause to get just questions...

Comment: I was going to also ask "If I run the following why is Users.DisplayName populated in the result set whereas Posts.OwnerDisplayName is blank ?" ...._the following_ being the same query as this questions `OP`. I've not got enough rep points to ask another question so soon.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - upped comment just for having the best user name I've seen.

Comment: @whytheq `Posts.OwnerDispalyName` is only populated in cases where the display name has been denormalized, such as in an account deletion or a community wiki post.

Comment: @TimStone - ok so not a field I need to worry about. Hey - is there a page with definitions of all the fields?

Comment: @whytheq There's [this slightly outdated schema overview](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer/2678#2678), but I'll make a note that something a bit more comprehensive might be helpful.